# No datarow shows up after setting the Grouping of my DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm creating a program that will show the application made by a certain resource. I'm planning to show all the application in a datagrid with grouping according to the month and year when did the application was assigned. I gather and tried may codes but I just managed to show the grouping header but the contents are not showing up.

Here are my codes:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="EXPAND" IsExpanded="False"
                              Background="White"
                              Foreground="Black">
                    <Expander.Header>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                         </Expander.Header>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AppID}" Header="App ID" Width="Auto" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ApplicationName}" Header="App Name" Width="0.30*" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="0.10*" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Category}" Header="Category" Width="Auto" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PackageType}" Header="Package Type" Width="0.10*" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>


                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

                </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void LoadTracker()
        {
            myMSIPID.procGetMSITrackByPID(dsApp.procGetMSITrackByPID,PID);

            ICollectionView cView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dsApp.procGetMSITrackByPID);

            cView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MonthYear"));

            dgAppTracker.DataContext = dsApp.procGetMSITrackByPID;
            dgAppTracker.ItemsSource = cView;

        }
```

Can anyone tell why aren't there any rows appearing in my program? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but did you forget to include a ContentPresenter in your control template definition? It seems to me that your control template is only defining the header, and there is no definition for how to display the content

Comment: Don't worry about my comment ... I failed to look at your second code block closely!

Comment: Hi thank you for your comments. I already resolved this problem. I just have to fix some of my XAML's codes. ^_^